# Modify attribute value of Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, model

I have a model `Order` and a model `Store`.

Whenever I wanna call the order model with store,

```
$order = Order::with('store')->first();
```

I want to change one of the store attributes as follows.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\OrderPoint;

class Order extends Model
{
    public function store()
    {
        $order_id = $this->id;
        $location = OrderPoint::where('order_id', $order_id)->first();
        if ($location)
        {
             // DO something that location value is changed on the 
             // store
             $this->store->location = $location;

        }
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
    }
}
```

Is this modification possible?

Comment: assuming you are not saving the updated property, you can look into [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). I think you should put the accessor on the `Store` Model instead of the `Order` Model.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on state (`$this->id`) in any relationship method will break eager loading (with) and the ability to query relations (whereHas).

Your specific example "could" work with a single model instance, but not in the way you're attempting to access the relationship within the same method